# Problem with previewing layer on geoserver ( instead of downloading wms file )

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, openlayers-2

When I hit OpenLayers to preview my layer in Geoserver, instead of opening a new tab with OpenLayers it automatically downloads a wms file
I just opened the wms file and says :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: There is a problem with your GeoServer, what does the rest of the message say?

Comment: You might find more information in the Tomcat logs.

Comment: Pease take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A site.  I think it will also be well worth you jumping to http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question

Comment: If you make a GetCapabilities request do you get an XML document or do you get an error?

Comment: solved thank you, the problem was with my database + postgis configuration,